# Best way to deploy java application on AWS using Netbeans?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, netbeans-7, amazon-rds

I have a publicly accessed database on RDS that works like a charm from Netbeans. I would like to deploy my Java application on AWS. What is the simplest way to do this? I will only use the application for some very basic tasks, getting used to cloud computing working on a small scale. Is EC2 my best bet and is it possible to upload apps as easily as with the Google App Engine plugin. Can I use the same jdbc driver as I use locally, and can I use JPA against the database? I would rather not use Eclipse for now as I am in a bit of a hurry and need to get this working as soon as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a lot of questions for one question, but I'll see if I can help you out.

**1. Simplest Way to deploy to AWS**

If this application is as simple as you say it is, the most cost effective solution while you're getting used to AWS will be to deploy to a micro instance and take advantage of [the free tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/). From Amazon:

> AWS Free Tier includes 750 hours of Linux and Windows Micro Instances each month for one year. To stay within the Free Tier, use only EC2 Micro instances.

The simplest way to deploy directly from Netbeans is to use the integrated [Elastic Beanstalk support](http://wiki.netbeans.org/AmazonBeanstalkSupport). This saves you from having to configure things yourself.

Another option is to launch a Ubuntu AMI and install Tomcat. Create a WAR file from your application and place it where Tomcat can find it. I suggest using the first method.

**2. Is EC2 my best bet?**

This is a little open ended. For a nice learning experience as you get accustomed to AWS, the free tier for EC2 is a nice platform to learn with. If your application needs to eventually scale, using EBS is a pretty simple way to manage an application. My answer is an opinion because "best bet" depends solely on the requirements of your application, but I say yes.

**3. Is it possible to upload apps as easily as with the Google App Engine plugin?**

For simple applications I think so. I think it's even easier if you switch to Eclipse and use the [toolkit for AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/). Whether Google App Engine or AWS is easier for you will once again depend on personal preference, the application, and your requirements.

**4. Can I use the same JDBC driver as I use locally?**

If you're using MySQL Connector/J then yes. [Read this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.rds.html) to understand how it works with RDS.

**5. Can I use JPA against the database?**

Yes. You'll change the endpoint from localhost to the endpoint of your RDS instance.

**6. I would rather not use Eclipse for now...**

Another personal preference, but the [AWS toolkit for Eclipse](http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/) is very easy to use and can speed the process up a bit.

Comment: You are a star! Thank you for answering my broad questions. You provided all the information needed to get me started. I will definitely give Eclipse a go. Thank you ever so much!